# Codename One - Method to enlarge or reduce all the fonts in all the styles

Tags: codenameone

Suppose that I have a Codename One app with a complex set of themes (that are overlayed) or  an app that has only one theme that is complex.

My question is if I can have simple Java code to enlarge or reduce by a given percentage all the font sizes (that are in mm) of all styles.

I know that I can overlay a theme that changes all the font sizes, but in some conditions can be painful.

Comment: What's painful about an overlay? Notice you can create a theme overlay programmatically since a theme is just a hashtable of key values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Shai and thank you tizbn, I meditated on both your answers. After that, I created the following method to do what I asked, maybe can be useful to other people.

```
/**
 * Increases or reduces of a given percentage all the font sizes of a given
 * theme, overlaying a new theme containing only the new font sizes. The
 * font sizes will be increased when the percentage is positive, they will
 * be reduced when the percentage is negative. Legal percentage values are
 * from -90 to 300.
 *
 * Example of usage: changeFontSizesOfTheme(theme, "Theme", 50);
 *
 * @param theme the given resource file
 * @param themeName the name of given theme
 * @param percentage the given percentage to increase or reduce the font
 * sizes
 */
public static void changeFontSizesOfTheme(Resources theme, String themeName, int percentage) {
    if (theme.isTheme(themeName) && percentage != 0 && percentage >= -90 && percentage <= 300) {
        Hashtable hashtable = theme.getTheme("Theme");
        Hashtable overlay = new Hashtable();
        Set<String> keys = hashtable.keySet();
        Iterator<String> itr = keys.iterator();
        String key;
        Object value;
        int count = 0;
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            key = itr.next();
            value = hashtable.get(key);
            if (value instanceof Font) {
                Font originalFont = (Font) value;
                float originalFontSize = originalFont.getPixelSize();
                float newFontSize = originalFontSize * (100 + percentage) / 100;
                overlay.put(key, originalFont.derive(newFontSize, originalFont.getStyle()));
                count++;
            }
        }
        UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(overlay);
        Log.p(count + " font sizes of the theme \"" + themeName + "\" were overlayed");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just openend a new question about this code because it doesn't work as expected: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851909/codename-one-modify-a-font-size-in-a-theme-like-in-an-hashtable

Answer (score 2):

```
int fontSize = Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(3);
Font tt  = Font.createTrueTypeFont(s, s).derive(fontSize, Font.STYLE_PLAIN);
```

For more ,please refer this link

https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Font.html