# Codename One - Modify a font size in a theme like in an hashtable

Tags: codenameone

In the previous question [Codename One - Method to enlarge or reduce all the fonts in all the styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48797731/codename-one-method-to-enlarge-or-reduce-all-the-fonts-in-all-the-styles) I replied with a method that iterates all the values of a theme and, if a given value is an istance of Font, it changes its font size of a given percentage.

The problem is that it doesn't work as expected, because some fonts are changed and others are not. For example, if I have the following font size of a Label (3.1mm) in my theme.xml, that Label font size it's not changed:

```
<font key="Label.font" type="ttf" face="0" style="0" size="0" name="native:MainThin" family="native:MainThin" sizeSettings="3" actualSize="3.1" />
```

What's wrong in the following code?

```
/**
 * Increases or reduces of a given percentage all the font sizes of a given
 * theme, overlaying a new theme containing only the new font sizes. The
 * font sizes will be increased when the percentage is positive, they will
 * be reduced when the percentage is negative. Legal percentage values are
 * from -90 to 300.
 *
 * Example of usage: changeFontSizesOfTheme(theme, "Theme", 50);
 *
 * @param theme the given resource file
 * @param themeName the name of given theme
 * @param percentage the given percentage to increase or reduce the font
 * sizes
 */
public static void changeFontSizesOfTheme(Resources theme, String themeName, int percentage) {
    if (theme.isTheme(themeName) && percentage != 0 && percentage >= -90 && percentage <= 300) {
        Hashtable hashtable = theme.getTheme("Theme");
        Hashtable overlay = new Hashtable();
        Set<String> keys = hashtable.keySet();
        Iterator<String> itr = keys.iterator();
        String key;
        Object value;
        int count = 0;
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            key = itr.next();
            value = hashtable.get(key);
            if (value instanceof Font) {
                Font originalFont = (Font) value;
                float originalFontSize = originalFont.getPixelSize();
                float newFontSize = originalFontSize * (100 + percentage) / 100;
                overlay.put(key, originalFont.derive(newFontSize, originalFont.getStyle()));
                count++;
            }
        }
        UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(overlay);
        Log.p(count + " font sizes of the theme \"" + themeName + "\" were overlayed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the key `Label.font` generated when you step over this with the debugger? What's the pixel value of the original vs. new size for that specific font? Do you `refreshTheme()` on the current `Form` after applying?

Comment: Thank you for the `refreshTheme()`, I've forgotten it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was the line:

```
    Hashtable hashtable = theme.getTheme("Theme");
```

The correct code is without the double quotes:

```
    Hashtable hashtable = theme.getTheme(Theme);
```

That's all :)