# Codename one - add UIID with Code When pressed

Tags: codenameone

I want to  add UIID with my Code

```
Style mystyle = new Style();
    mystyle.setBgColor(0x0x3F51B5);
    mystyle.setFgColor(0xFFFFFF);
    mystyle.setAlignment(Button.CENTER);
    mystyle.setBorder(RoundBorder.create()
            .rectangle(true)
            .color(0x0x3F51B5).opacity(255)
            .stroke(new Stroke(3, Stroke.CAP_SQUARE, Stroke.JOIN_MITER, 20))
            .strokeColor(0xff).strokeOpacity(10));
UIManager.getInstance().setComponentStyle("mystyle", myStyle);
UIManager.getInstance().setComponentSelectedStyle("mystyle", myStyle);
```

it works **BUT** when i pressed the Button it changed to normal text without style ,
I used : 
`UIManager.getInstance().setComponentStyle("buttonY", myStyle,"pressed");`

but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, you should have used `press` and not `pressed` as:

```
UIManager.getInstance().setComponentStyle("mystyle", myStyle,"press");
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851909/codename-one-modify-a-font-size-in-a-theme-like-in-an-hashtable) for a different approach to dynamically changing global styles.

Comment: It could be because I copied the `"buttonY"` String from your sample code. Looking again I see you used `"mystyle"` lower case for the name. Could this be it?

Comment: Nein , it works good without press but if i pressed it changed

Comment: Is that the old style or some other effect? Notice that Android styling has a special ripple effect